# Read several files in different directories and storing the line number in a list

Tags: python, text

I have a list with 46 subdirectories and I want to read the number of lines written in the .txt files present in each subdirectory. After that, I want to store the number of lines in each file inside a list.
I tried the code bellow but it didn't work:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def count_lines(paths):
    return sum(len(p.read_text().splitlines()) for p in paths)

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes/"
paths = Path(path).glob("*/*.txt")
count_lines(paths)
```

But instead of something along the lines of this:

```
['216063','180','2200','1104',...,'21171','12521','2069']
```

I get this:

```
2768046
```

What do I need to change so that I can have a list instead of the total number of lines?

I'm sorry if I duplicated questions but I couldn't find anything similar in Python.

Comment: "it didn't work" is the least helpful phrase. If it worked then you wouldn't ask for help. How did it not work? What do you get now and how is it different from what you want?

Comment: `return [len(p.read_text().splitlines()) for p in paths]`